# mathjax notation for a matrix in Blogger page

Tags: blogger, mathjax

I am trying to produce below equation in my blogger page

[image]

using Mathjax notation :

```
$\begin{bmatrix} 230.1 & 37.8 & 69.8 \\ 44.5 & -39.3 & 45.1 \\ 17.2 & -45.9 & 69.3 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\ 8.6 & 2.1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \\ \beta_3 \end{bmatrix}$=$\beta_1$\begin{bmatrix} 230.1 \\ 44.5 \\ 17.2 \\ \vdots \\ 8.6 \end{bmatrix}+$\beta_2$\begin{bmatrix} 37.8 \\ -39.3 \\- 45.9 \\ \vdots \\ 2.1 \end{bmatrix}+$\beta_3$\begin{bmatrix} 69.8 \\ 45.1 \\ 69.3 \\ \vdots \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}
```

but above Mathjax renders as

[image]

Please suggest how to structure Mathjax so that it renders in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the dollar signs except the one at the beginning and the end.  You might want to use double dollars at the beginning and end, as this is better as a display equation than an in-line one.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>

Your expression:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 230.1 & 37.8 & 69.8 \\ 44.5 & -39.3 & 45.1 \\ 17.2 & -45.9 & 69.3 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\ 8.6 & 2.1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \\ \beta_3 \end{bmatrix}=\beta_1\begin{bmatrix} 230.1 \\ 44.5 \\ 17.2 \\ \vdots \\ 8.6 \end{bmatrix}+\beta_2\begin{bmatrix} 37.8 \\ -39.3 \\- 45.9 \\ \vdots \\ 2.1 \end{bmatrix}+\beta_3\begin{bmatrix} 69.8 \\ 45.1 \\ 69.3 \\ \vdots \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}$$
```

I have used MathJax version 3, here, but you can use version 2.7 just as well. Note that I removed your dollar signs, and used `$$` at the beginning **and end** of the expression, so that the entire equation is within (double) dollar signs.

Comment: I tried  this expression - "$\beta_1$\begin{bmatrix} 230.1 \\ 44.5 \\ 17.2 \\ \vdots \\ 8.6\end{bmatrix}". If I remove $, it does not even render beta.

Comment: I've added a live example to my answer.  You need to have move the second dollar sign to the **end** of the expression (after the `\end{matrix}`).  There should only be dollar signs at the beginning and the end of the entire equation.  You are missing the delimiter at the end of the expression.